# PL/SQL: Passing lexical parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

i want to pass a whole sql query as a lexical parameter to a stored procedure and then execute it. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute it"? A query is designed to return a result - you need to define what you want the stored procedure to do with the results.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,
What i want to do is give the query at runtime to a stored procedure, for example i want to perform insert operation i will give insert query at runtime when i execute the procedure.

Comment: Will the query always return the same set of columns and data types?

Comment: No because if thats the case there will be no need to pass whole querry.

Comment: It's not clear what you need this procedure for then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this:

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(pstring IN varchar2)
is

begin

  if length(pstring)>0 then

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE pstring;

  end if;

end my_proc;
```

here is the official oracle documentation on dynamic plsql : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD

Comment: Be very, very, very sure that you don't have another way to do this? Executing unknown SQL can be very dangerous, and an attacker, if they come across this, can basically do anything to your database...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "lexical" parameter but you can pass the SQL query in as a VARCHAR2 then execute it using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
i am doing this.
create or replace procedure testproc(str varchar2(1000)) as is
begin
execute immediate (str);
end;

Is this the correct way or i am missing something?

Comment: Leave out the "(1000)" as you don't specify the length of IN parameters.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is almost certainly the wrong way to go.

`Execute Immediate` is to be used with caution because it can a) impose a security risk and b) cause negative effects on performance when many distinct SQL statements are run that way.

However, see [here](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/execute-immediate-insert-into,3) how to insert records using `execute immediate`. Note that it's essential to use bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a **query** (as opposed to a DML [insert, update, delete] or a PL/SQL block of code), you can do something like this:

```
function get_dataset (p_sql_query in varchar2) return sys_refcursor
as
  l_returnvalue sys_refcursor;
begin

  open l_returnvalue for p_sql_query;

  return l_returnvalue;

end get_dataset;
```

The return value is a "weakly typed" REF CURSOR.

The calling program (whether it is Java, .NET, PL/SQL, whatever) must then process the function result and close the cursor.

Comment: Thanx ObiWanKenobi, this is useful.